# PhpWord is there a way to insert a specific code in PHP to generate automatically the today date in word document?

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

I am using the **phpWord library** and i want to know if there is a way to insert specific code into the word docx generated by the phpWord library so that when i open in few days my word doc the date in the word doc will be automatically updated at the current day.

Let's say i generate the word donc on Dec 21 and i open the word doc on Dec 29 i need the date on my word doc to be automatically updated.

Made lot of research but unable to find the solution ;(

Thanks in advance !

Comment: phpword supports doc templates, in there you can have a custom entry which represents the current date and is parsed at runtime. Check phpword templates for further info

Answer (score 0):

No, There is no magic function like that, which you can bind with your generated word file and it checks if it's the first time the file is getting opened, then change the very first line of the word file into current timestamp followed by the date format you used.

Short Answer

```
"No"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution thanks to Nikos M.

Had to deal with template. Create from scratch my doc from word, add specific date text function inside word.

Use ${my_var} in my doc word and populate from phpWord. Date keeps the word anatomy code and i update only my var. It is possible from templating i didn't know templating because it was the first time i used phpWord.

Thanks